# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'tzHour' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

trying to get the following to work, trying to make adjustment for timezone. If I comment out the line AND plan.resetHour=tzHour it shows the column tzHour correctly but can't seem to use the value in the where clause.

```
SELECT
     `issuer`.`tz`
    ,`account`.`id`
    , `plan`.`endDate`
    , `plan`.`resetDay`
    , `plan`.`resetHour`
    , `plan`.`type`
    , HOUR(NOW())
    ,   CASE issuer.`tz`
        WHEN 'US/Eastern' THEN HOUR(NOW())+1
        WHEN 'US/Central' THEN HOUR(NOW())
        ELSE HOUR(NOW())
    END AS tzHour

FROM
    `dvh`.`account`
    INNER JOIN `dvh`.`plan` 
        ON (`account`.`plan` = `plan`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `dvh`.`issuer` 
        ON (`plan`.`issuer` = `issuer`.`id`)        
WHERE plan.type='UNIT' 
AND plan.startDate < NOW() 
AND plan.endDate >NOW() 
AND plan.resetDay=DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
AND plan.resetHour=tzHour
AND account.`active`=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a column alias in a WHERE clause is illegal. From MySQL docs:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html

One way to go about this is to move the case into a sub-select.

```
SELECT
     `issuer`.`tz`
    ,`account`.`id`
    , `plan`.`endDate`
    , `plan`.`resetDay`
    , `plan`.`resetHour`
    , `plan`.`type`
    , HOUR(NOW())
    , tempHour.tzHour
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            CASE `tz`
                WHEN 'US/Eastern' THEN HOUR(NOW())+1
                WHEN 'US/Central' THEN HOUR(NOW())
                ELSE HOUR(NOW())
            END AS tzHour
        FROM issuer
    ) AS tempHour,
    `dvh`.`account`
    INNER JOIN `dvh`.`plan` 
        ON (`account`.`plan` = `plan`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `dvh`.`issuer` 
        ON (`plan`.`issuer` = `issuer`.`id`)        
WHERE plan.type='UNIT' 
AND plan.startDate < NOW() 
AND plan.endDate >NOW() 
AND plan.resetDay=DAYOFWEEK(NOW())
AND plan.resetHour=tempHour.tzHour
AND account.`active`=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by moving case to where clause

```
AND plan.`resetHour` = 
    CASE 
        WHEN issuer.`tz`='US/Eastern' THEN HOUR(NOW())+1
        WHEN issuer.`tz`='US/Central' THEN HOUR(NOW())
        WHEN issuer.`tz`='US/Mountain' THEN HOUR(NOW())-1
        WHEN issuer.`tz`='US/Pacific' THEN HOUR(NOW())-2
    END
```